# Проблема с кодировкой широкими символами

Tags: c++, кодировка

Здравствуйте, в институте задали написать консольное приложение, работающее с txt файлом (запись/чтение). Задачу осуществил, но возникла проблема с кодировкой, преподаватель посоветовал использовать широкие символы, после их использования программа перестала работать, при считывании из файла - зацикливается.

Вот код файла с классом:

```
class my  
{  
public:  
    vector <int> number;  
    vector <wstring> name;  
    vector <wstring> patronymic;  
    vector <wstring> surname;  
    vector <wstring> sex;  
    vector <wstring> stat;  
    vector <wstring> guest;

    void output_workers();
    void add_workers();
    void del_workres();
    void memory_clear();
};

И код функции:

void my::add_workers()  
    {  
        int in;  
        wstring st;  
        char ch, point;   
        float fl;  
        wifstream f("db.txt");  
        f.imbue(locale(".ACP"));  
        while (true)  
        {  
            if (!f.eof())  
            {  
                f >> in; number.push_back(in);  
                f >> st; name.push_back(st);  
                f >> st; patronymic.push_back(st);  
                f >> st; surname.push_back(st);  
                f >> st; sex.push_back(st);  
                f >> st; stat.push_back(st);  
                f >> st; guest.push_back(st);  
            }  
            else  
                break;  
        }  
        if ( number.size() < 98)  
        {  
            cout << "Внесение в БД нового участника" << endl;  
            cout << "Введите номер: "; cin >> in;   
            for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++)  
            {  
                if (in == number[i])  
                {  
                    system ("cls");
                    cout << "Внесение в БД нового участника" << endl;  
                    cout << "Введённый вами номер уже существует..."<< endl;  
                    cout << "Введите новый: "; cin >> in;  
                    i = -1;  
                }  
            }  
            number.push_back(in);  
            wcout << L"Введите имя: "; wcin >> st; name.push_back(st);  
            wcout << L"Введите отчество: "; wcin >> st; patronymic.push_back(st);  
            wcout << L"Введите фамилию: "; wcin >> st; surname.push_back(st);  
            wcout << L"Выберете пол: "<<endl<< L"1 - Мужской;"<<endl<< L"2 - Женский"<<endl; wcin >> st; sex.push_back(L"Мужской");  
            wcout << L"Выберете статус участника: "<<endl<< L"1 - Студент"<<"2 - Аспирант"<< L"3 - Преподаватель"<<endl; wcin >> st; stat.push_back(L"Студент");  
            wcout << L"Выберете роль участника: "<<endl<<L"1 - Выступающий"<<endl<< L"2 - Гость"<<endl; wcin >> st;  guest.push_back(L"Выступающий");  
            system ("cls");   
            wcout << "Вы уверены что хотите добавить участника: " << endl;  
            wcout << name[name.size()-1] << " ";  
            wcout << patronymic[patronymic.size()-1] << " ";  
            wcout << surname[surname.size()-1] << " ";  
            //cout << sex[sex.size()-1] << " ";  
            //cout << stat[stat.size()-1] << " ";  
            wcout << guest[guest.size()-1] << " (y/n?) "; cin >> point;  
            if (point == 'y')  
            {  
                for(int i = guest.size()-1; i > 0; i--)  
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j ++)  
                    {  
                        if (number[j] > number[j+1])  
                        {  
                            swap(number[j],number[j+1]);  
                            swap(name[j],name[j+1]);  
                            swap(patronymic[j],patronymic[j+1]);  
                            swap(surname[j],surname[j+1]);  
                            swap(sex[j],sex[j+1]);  
                            swap(stat[j],stat[j+1]);  
                            swap(guest[j],guest[j+1]);  
                        }  
                    }

                wofstream of("db.txt");  
                for (int i = 0; i < guest.size(); i++)  
                {  
                    of << number[i] << " ";  
                    of << name[i] << " ";   
                    of << patronymic[i] << " ";  
                    of << surname[i] << " ";  
                    of << sex[i] << " ";  
                    of << stat[i] << " ";  
                    if (i+1 < guest.size())   
                        of << guest[i] << endl;  
                    else   
                        of << guest[i];  
                }  
            }  
            memory_clear();  
            system ("cls");  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            cout << "Отказ от выполнения операции" << endl;  
            system ("pause");  
            system ("cls");  
        }  
    }
```

Зацикливается в этом месте:

```
while (true) 
 { 
 if (!f.eof()) 
 { 
 f >> in; number.pushback(in);
```

И почему - понять не могу. Подскажите, кто чем может..

Comment: Наверное не зацикливается, а ждет ввода (висит на операторе f >> in) ?

Если так, то видимо ждет **десятичное число**, а на входе его нет. Перепишите ввод на stdio и все станет ясно.

Comment: Насмотревшись на количество вопросов, появившихся в последнее время, по C++ и русским символам в консоли, хочется дать дурацкий совет:

**не пишите на плюсах**, будьте проще.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [**ответ на этот вопрос**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/43894/178576), возможно, не совсем предсказуемое поведение связано именно с механикой работы `stream::eof()`.

И, кстати говоря, считается правилом хорошего тона не использовать `std::wcout` и `std::cout` *(равно как и пару `std::wcin` и `std::cin`)* в пределах одного приложения.