# Баг fptr.eof()

Tags: c++

Почему если использовать fptr.eof() и считывать по символу, то он последним символом считывает (-1 'я'), хотя его там нет! Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать конструкцию `istream.peek() < 0` для проверки на EOF.

Comment: Вариант Алексея мне отлично подошел. Спасибо. Буду иметь ввиду на будущее.

Answer (score 4):

При работе с `fstream` в `C++` нельзя использовать `fstream::eof()` как условие выхода из цикла. *Это - деталь реализации, более подробно можно прочитать, например, [здесь.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764579/eof-problem-c)*

Если вкратце, то `eof() function returns "true" after the program attempts to read past the end of the file`, то есть сам флаг `eof()` устанавливается лишь после того, **как была попытка прочитать за пределами файла.**

---

В таком случае, возврат `-1` в вашем случае - это как раз и есть попытка прочитать *"за пределами файла"*, после которой и устанавливается соответствующий факт *(`-1` соответствует коду `EOF` в реализации стримов).*

Вообще говоря, это не самая очевидная часть стримов, но существует достаточно добротное объяснение, почему это реализовано именно таким образом. Если интересно, то могу разъяснить.

---

Хороший способ прочитать файл в стиле `C++` подразумевает испольование `istream_iterator'ов`, как пример:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream stream("input.file");
std::string s((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)),
               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

В случае, *если известно, что файл большой и не хочется полностью доверяться механизму реаллокации памяти*, работающему внутри `std::string`, то решение может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
std::ifstream stream("input.file");
std::string s;

stream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);   
s.reserve(stream.tellg());
stream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

s.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```